# Prism and nested UserControl

Tags: user-controls, prism

I have been using Prism for two days and have successfully added and used existing UserControls on the new Shell. These UserControls contained only pure WPF Controls (buttons, lists etc).

I now need to introduce existing UserControls that consists of other UserControls.

If my understanding is correct, I believe I need to redevelop these controls to use regions in the same manner as the shell, and define a Run() method on an appropriate controller/presenter to have the (sub)UserControl injected.

Is this Correct?